# Load pandas DataFrame to pyarrow table with decimal column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyarrow

I am trying to load pandas DataFrame to pyarrow Table with float column and have an issue during pyarrow Table construction: `ArrowTypeError: ('int or Decimal object expected, got float', 'Conversion failed for column float_column with type object')`

The code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
from decimal import Decimal, Context

float_value = 1.2

print(type(float_value))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[float_value]], columns=["float_column"], dtype="object")

schema_dict = {"float_column":pa.decimal128(32, 6)}
schema = pa.schema(schema_dict)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema)
```

The DataFrame itself is coming from `pandas.read_sql_query` method and the underlying type in the db is decimal(32,6).

The question is: **How to specify SQL decimal(32,6) type in pandas DataFrame and convert such DataFrame to pyarrow Table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anyway, the problem was deeper than I anticipated. pyodbc, used to read from SQL db, was returning proper Decimal object. pandas, by default was [converting values of non-string, non-numeric objects to floating point](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

so the solution is to use coerce_float=False in the pandas.read_sql method.